# Eloquent Query for getting all user failed transactions where user has no completed transactions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm having difficulty building an eloquent query to provide a dashboard of transactions that are issue cases. Issues are defined as all failed transactions where the user has not completed a transaction.

I have two tables, `users` and `transactions`. A user can have many transactions, and a transaction can have a status of either `completed` or `failed`.

I need a single eloquent query to get a list of failed transactions from all users who have at least one failed transaction, and have not had any completed transactions. I currently approached this from the other direction by querying for users rather than transactions

```
$failed_transactions = User::has('transactions')->whereDoesntHave('transactions', function($query) {
     $query->where('status', 'completed');
})->get();
```

The issue is that it returns a list of users rather than failed transactions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a single eloquent query to get a list of failed transactions from all users who have at least one failed transaction, and have not had any completed transactions.

If you want to get a failed transactions collection:

```
Transaction::whereHas('user.transactions', function($q) {
        $q->where('status', 'failed');
    })
    ->whereDoesntHave('user.transactions', function($q) {
        $q->where('status', 'completed');
    })
    ->where('status', 'failed')
    ->get()
```

If you want to get users with their failed transactions:

```
User::whereHas('transactions', function($q) {
        $q->where('status', 'failed');
    })
    ->whereDoesntHave('transactions', function($q) {
        $q->where('status', 'completed');
    })
    ->with(['transactions' => function($q) {
        $q->where('status', 'failed');
    }])
    ->get()
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey, works a charm. How come you need the final `->where('status', 'failed')` for the first query as well as the `whereHas()`?

Comment: @frostfat `whereHas()` checks if a user has failed transactions and `where()` gets only failed transactions.